# How to remove Days off from azure TFS 2019 calendar board

Tags: azure-devops

I was able to add days off to my team's calendar but weekends are counted in the total days off count. I want to remove the days off that are added in the weekends. How can I do that?
[image]

I can't remove any of the added days as well. There is no option here to remove'em.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues/248) on the extension calendar. We cannot remove the weekends days off from the calendar page. Though the days off show in weekends, the capacity is not affected by it, we could navigate to sprint->capacity page to check it.

[image]

**Update1**

Open calendar page->click the user icon, then we could see the days off details, we can update the days off date or click the button **Delete days off** to remove these days all together.

[image]

**Update2**

This seems to be a [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues/321) with this extension.

We recommend that you remove these days via TFS feature.

Steps: Click Sprints->capacity->select the user->click the Days off `xxx Days`->click the button X to remove these days. We could refer the pic below.

There are some prerequisites, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops-2019#prerequisites) for more details

[image]

Comment: what if I want to remove these days all together.

Comment: Hi @Fadwa, I have updated the answer, please check the update1

Comment: I updated the question. Can't find this option.

Comment: Hi @Fadwa, I have shared TFS feature to delete these days, please check the update2